# How to specify which TestNG test to be executed at run time

Tags: java, testng

I want to include following feature in my automation testing frmework

- Specify test case id (unique alphanumeric id) along with each test
  method. (singles class may contain several test methods)
- When an excel sheet    containing some of the above test cases is uploaded, all the    specified test cases should be    executed in
  the order specified in the    excel sheet

How to do these using TestNG and Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Specify test case id - just create annotation or use something like
   [allure](http://allure.qatools.ru/).
2. When an excel sheet containing... - I see it as a job on CI server
   which would triger a jar to parse your excel and code, match cases with metods using
   test case ids and generate testng.xml with requred tests and order.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can help you http://www.randomsync.net/2012/02/excel-testng-driving-testng-tests.html

I have not tested this.......try your luck and let us know if it works...